# Proving a function is not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, derivatives

Given the function $f(x) = |8x^3 − 1|$ in the set $A = [0, 1].$
Prove that the function is not differentiable at $x = \frac12.$

The answer in my book is as follows:

$$\lim_{x \to \frac12-} \dfrac{f(x)-f(1/2)}{x-1/2} = -6$$ 
$$\lim_{x \to \frac12+} \dfrac{f(x)-f(1/2)}{x-1/2} = 6$$

Can anyone explain how the $6$'s were derived. I understand that as $x$ tends to $\frac12$ from the negative side, the bottom will be negative, so thats why the first one is a minus.

But how do you get to the $6$, what am I missing? Obviously $f(\frac12)=0$ but what do you make $f(x)=$ as $x$ tends to $\frac12$

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f_+(x)= 8x^3-1$, $f_-(x) = 1-8x^3$, these are both smooth.

In the following $f$ is the function the OP defined. (I am not redefining $f$.)

If $x \ge { 1\over 2}$ then $f(x) = f_+(x)$.

If $x \le { 1\over 2}$ then $f(x) = f_-(x)$.

Hence the one sided derivatives of $f$ will match the derivatives of $f_+,f_-$
as appropriate.

Comment: Fantastic! You answered my hint!

Comment: @RobArthan: I can't tell whether you are being facetious or not. In either case, I did not compute the derivative of your $g$ at $x={1 \over 2}$. In fact, my provison of $f'$ above is a red herring which I should correct.

Comment: Not facetious - just being light-hearted about parallel work on the same question $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: Happens a lot here :-). My typing skills are of a particularly pedestrian two fingered variety, which doesn't help...

Comment: Alright you want to be pedantic about derivatives? Then it's not the derivatives of $f_+,f_-$ but the limit of those derivatives in the appropriate directions. If by $f_+$ you include the point itself, then it's the one-sided derivatives you are talking about, unless your definition of derivative is the kind that classifies functions on the natural numbers as differentiable. =)

Comment: Oh sorry I thought your $f_-,f_+$ were the left and right part respectively, in which case they technically won't be differentiable at the endpoint of their domain under the usual definition.

Comment: Yes I know. I was joking about that, but it backfired when I misinterpreted what you wrote...

Comment: I'm deleting the relevant comments...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $f(x) = |g(x)|$ where $g(x) = 8x^3 - 1$. What is the derivative of $g(x)$ when $x = \frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 1):

$(8x^3-1)/(x-1/2)=8(x^3-1/8)/(x-1/2)=8(x^2+(1/2)x+1/4)$, which is equal to 6 at $x=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost easier to prove a more general result: If $f(a) = 0$ and $f'(a) \ne 0,$ then $|f(x)|$ is not differentiable at $a.$